# htaccess file does not take me to 404 error page

Tags: .htaccess

I have created a .htaccess file and placed it in my root directory for 404 error page, but when I type a random subdirectory after my URL, it takes me to the index.php file instead of my 404.php file. I have the following code in my .htaccess file.

ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you don't post your full `.htaccess` file nobody can help you.

Comment: This is the only line I have in the .htaccess file

Comment: shouldn't your `404.php` file be in the error directory instead of root directory?

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mention this, but I do have 404.php file in my error directory.

Comment: Could you make an example of a url that shouldn't work, but takes you to index.php?

Comment: Let's say my website is example.com. I have tried something like example.com/dsajfljdsafdsa, and I thought that should take me to 404.php page, but it takes me to index.php

Comment: Are you sure that your web-server can handle the `.htaccess` file? That said try to give a look to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7426870/4999641), maybe it will convince you to use a `.html` file for your erreor-page.

Answer (score 0):

`/error/404.php` indicates your file location is `/var/www/html/error/404.php`

If the name of your project directory is, lets say `myweb`, then your `.htaccess` should be

```
ErrorDocument 404 /myweb/error/404.php
```

Comment: You mean, if my website is example.com, the .htaccess file should be

ErrorDocument 404 /example.com/error/404.php

?

Comment: You should specify full path. Specify folder name not domain name. what is the name of your website directory?

Comment: I have placed the .htaccess file at my root directory. Say my web site is example.com. .htaccess file is at example.com/.htaccess, and 404.php file is at example.com/error/404.php

Comment: Which directory does example.com point to? Also can you access 404.php file by hitting http://example.com/error/404.php in the browser?

Comment: I don't understand your first question. It should point to the root directory. Second question, yes, I can access it with example.com/error/404.php

Comment: With root directory I meant the directory of your website code. Let's say code of my website example.com is present in /var/www/html/myweb/. So myweb will be the root directory. Since you can access 404.php through example.com/error/404.php, the absolute path will be /var/www/html/myweb/error/404.php. So, in .htaccess the path should be /myweb/error/404.php.